# Python Help Pandas row and Column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am kind of new to python, but I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  NAME        NAME1      VALUE
1   Sarah       orange     5
1   Roger       apple      3
2   Amy         pineapple  2
2   Kia         pear       8
```

I want it like this:

```
ID NAME   NAME1     VALUE  NAME   NAME1  VALUE
1  Sarah  orange     5     Roger  apple   3
2  Amy    pineapple  2     Kia    pear    8
```

I am using pandas but not sure how I can achieve this and write to a `csv`. Any help would highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can not have same column name in a dataframe.

Comment: @Sociopath Yes I meant to say that I want to rename it to Name_1 Name_2 etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for `MultiIndex`, reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sort `MulitIndex` by second level by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last flatten it by list comprehension with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['ID',df.groupby('ID').cumcount()]).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
#python 3.6+
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
#python bellow 3.6
#df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(a,b) for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   ID NAME_0    NAME1_0  VALUE_0 NAME_1 NAME1_1  VALUE_1
0   1  Sarah     orange        5  Roger   apple        3
1   2    Amy  pineapple        2    Kia    pear        8
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but getting a value error, all arrays must be of same length?

Comment: @dtev1345 - What code raise error? There are missing values in `id` ?

Comment: Yes, there are NaNs I think, I need to remove those rows with NaN in id and then do this I think? Also, when I write this to a csv I am doing df.to_csv('test.csv', 'index=false'). Right now, my excel looks messed up, but it should work, am I right? Thanks!

Comment: @dtev1345 - So it depends. Simpliest is remove them by `df = df.dropna(subset=['id'])` before my solution. But if need them, then use `df['id'] = df['id'].fillna('missing')`, apply my solution and last `df['id'] = df['id'].replace('missing', np.nan)`. Here is problem `groupby` remove NaNs rows by default.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still confused on the writing this to an excel, right now the excel is looking very scattered!

Comment: @dtev1345 - are data confidental?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately!

Comment: so do you use dropna solution?

Comment: @dtev1345 - So what does mean `right now the excel is looking very scattered!` ? Can you explain more?